# Click a graph icon using selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, protractor, specflow

I am unable to click a graph icon in a Angular8 project.

Comment: Should you not call `ngDriver.WaitForAngular()` _before_ trying to find and click an element rendered by angluar..?

Comment: Hi, I have called ngDriver.WaitForAngular()  in the previous step at the end of it.

Comment: could you give us more of the error message?  the single line shown here looks like just one line of a stack trace indicating the location of the failure, not the exception being raised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception you are getting, `OpenQA.Selenium.WebDriverTimeoutException`, occurs in your waiting method `NgWebDriver.WaitForAngular()`. This shows that the WebDriver is waiting for something to appear/be clickable/etc, but fails to do so before reaching the waiting time limit.

Just by guessing from the structure and class names of your HTML, the element you are trying to click could be either of;

- Inside/covered by another element, i.e. the i-element inside the button, or is the element you actually want to click beneath the i-element ?
- The element is hidden, and since selenium is designed to fail such clicks, it fails to click this element.

I suggest that you experiment with clicking on the parent element, or see if there is another child element that you should click. If that fails, you could also try clicking with a JavascriptExecutor:

```
public void ClickUsingJquery(string selector) {
    string script = String.Format("jQuery(\"{0}\").click();", selector);
    TestContext.WriteLine("Script to execute: " + script);
    var javaScriptExecutor = this.driver as IJavaScriptExecutor; 
    javaScriptExecutor?.ExecuteScript(script);
}
```

(Replace `getElementById('{elementId}').click()` and the `selector` parameter with whatever way of selecting your element you prefer).

Comment: Hi @Agent Shoulder,

I have tried to click td, button, i and inside the i element itself but none of them work. I have tried with XPath and CSS for all. I will try Java executor now and get back to you.

Thanks

Comment: Hi @Agent Shoulder,

How would I implement this in my code? I think I am doing something wrong/ something is missing as it doesn't like TestContext.WriteLine. I get the following error: https://imgur.com/l4wifnr

Comment: Hi @Agent Shoulder,
I am not sure if it is to do with the element in application or the wait in the script.

Comment: You can just skip the logging part (TestContect.Writeline) if that causes you trouble @Hifitech

Comment: Even after adding Ids to the element it is still failing. This may be in relation to Keylines. As for this page uses keylines, I think that Angular wait is unable to determine that the keylines graph has loaded on the page. I believe this is the reason for the test to fail.

Answer (score 0):

You could be encountering an issue with the XPath you are using. I suggest using one that queries directly on the button element:

```
    NgWebElement GraphIcon = ngDriver.FindElement(By.XPath("//button[contains(@class, 'btnItems') and *[contains(@class, 'fa-line-chart')]]"));
```

Comment: I made the suggested changes but the graph still did not open and the test failed. @Christine

Comment: Was it the same error message as before? It's possible that the button is nested in an `iframe` element and this is why the click is unsuccessful.

Comment: Same error as before @Christine. It might be will find out and confirm tomorrow but I don't think that is the case.

Comment: The XPaths used in your example, and suggested by other users, all seem perfectly valid, so if they are not working then it is likely due to some outside factor that is not represented in the question body. If you post the full HTML for the page you are automating, the community may be able to give you better answers.

Comment: Hi @Christine, I am trying to add the HTML past 2 days but StackOverflow is giving me the following error. I have contacted the team but still has not been fixed as of yet.

Comment: No worries, I am still receiving notifications from this post so I will try to update the answer once you are able to post the HTML.